# How to compress file on angular 8 production build

Tags: angular, performance, zip, compression

We need to improve performance of website, that was built in angular 8

> How to compress (gzip/brotli) angular file on production build?

Comment: Can you share more details? Number of components, file sizes, assets included (and their formats). Can we assume you have taken basic steps such as image compression and using common NPM modules rather custom built ones? Are you able to link to a GitHub repository?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two ways:

1. Use the webpack compression plugin. `npm i compression-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

Then add the plugin to your webpack config. For example:

```
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new CompressionPlugin()],
};
```

2. gzip all assets after the build by using gzipper

   `npm i gzipper --save-dev`

   `ng build && gzipper dist/app --log`